# Why is there a margin between my button and the neighbouring div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML and am wondering why there is a margin between my "equals" button and the neighbouring buttons (3 and .)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-4">1</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">2</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-8">0</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <button class="col-md-12" id="equal">=</button>
      <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[screen shot of described margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbXwv.png)

Comment: This is because bootstrap columns has a padding of 15px.

Comment: if you want to remove padding you can wrap button in <div class="row"> class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-xs-4">1</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">2</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-xs-8">0</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="col-xs-1" id="equal">=</button>
      <br/>
</div>
```

You are getting a gap because there is a padding of 15px for bootstrap columns. So I made a few changes to your code and removed the parent div wrapper for the button with `=` sign and added `col-xs-1` class to it. You can add `col-xs-3` if you wish.

Note that I have also changed all the classes from `col-md-` to `col-xs-` which is entirely optional. You can keep it `md`. I have added `xs` so that the result can be seen on the preview screen.

**SOLUTION 2:**

```css
.equal-wrapper {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-xs-4">1</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">2</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-xs-8">0</button>
      <button class="col-xs-4">.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 equal-wrapper">
     <button class="col-xs-12" id="equal">=</button>
      <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using your second solution and used height: 100% on my button to make it span two rows and it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your button in a **row**, bootstrap columns have padding by default.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row calculator">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-4">1</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">2</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-8">0</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-12" id="equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Check the above example in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

Add a class `calculator`

```
<div class="row calculator">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-4">1</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">2</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-8">0</button>
      <button class="col-md-4">.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <button class="col-md-12" id="equal">=</button>
      <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
Remove Paddings.

```
.calculator .col-md-9{
    padding-right:0;
}

.calculator .col-md-3{
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to wrap button tag in row class like below code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-md-4">1</button>
        <button class="col-md-4">2</button>
        <button class="col-md-4">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="col-md-8">0</button>
        <button class="col-md-4">.</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <button class="col-md-12" id="equal">=</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```